# Pythonic way to create a 2d array?

Tags: python

I want to create a 2d array of integer values initially set to 0.

This is how I would think to do it:

```
grid = [[0] * width] * height
```

But this just creates each row as a reference to the original, so doing something like

```
grid[0][1] = 1
```

will modify all of the grid[n][1] values.

This is my solution:

```
grid = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
```

It feels wrong, is there a better more pythonic way to do this?

EDIT: 
Bonus question, if the grid size is never going to change and will only contain integers should I use something like a tuple or array.array instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since numbers are immutable, using * to create a list should be fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20739302/1903116). So, the 2D list initialization can be done like this

```
[[0] * width for y in range(height)]
```

Comment: why not: `[[0]*width]*height`

Comment: @zeffii That will create only one list `[0]*width]` (think of this as `l1`) and create a list with `height` elements in which, all of them are the references to `l1`. So, changing any list will reflect on all the other lists as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

```
import numpy as np
numpy.zeros(height, width)
```

If it has to be integer use as option `dtype=numpy.int8`

Comment: Yea I've done it with numpy before but I'm trying to avoid external dependencies for my current project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used.

```
def generate_board(n): #Randomly creates a list with n lists in it, and n random numbers
                       #in each mini list
    list = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        list.append([])
        for j in range(0, n):
            list[i].append(random.randint(0, 9))
    return list

def print_board(board):
    n = len(board) - 1
    while n > -1:
        print str(board[n]) + ' = ' + str(n)
        n -= 1
```